# Solve the equation $xy=x+2y+2009$ in integers

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-functions, hyperbolic-equations

I know that the left side is a hyperbola and the right hand side is a line. So they have at most 2 solutions. I set $xy=k$ and solved for $y$, and after that substituted it on the right side.

The numbers are getting too big and the corresponding quadratic equation seems to be unsolvable without a calculator. Thank you.

Comment: "The left side is a hyperbola and the right hand side is a line. So they have at most 2 solutions" is incorrect. For any fixed value like $12345$, setting $xy=12345$ gives a hyperbola and setting $x+2y+2009=12345$ gives a line, so there's at most 2 (real) solutions. But since we can replace $12345$ by any other number we want, there's infinitely many real solutions. In fact, overall, $xy = x+2y+2009$ is another hyperbola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as $(x-2)(y-1) = 2011.$

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just to finish up @md2perpe's solution:

$$\{ \{x = -2009, y = 0\}, \{x = 1, y = -2010 \}, \{x = 3, 
  y = 2012\}, \{x = 2013, y = 2 \} \}$$

Comment: Thank you very much